# Can I declare Cursor inside anonymous Block In SQLSCRIPT

Tags: sql, hana, hana-sql-script

Is there any way to Declare A cursor inside anonymous Block In SQLSCRIPT .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
DO 
BEGIN

DECLARE CURSOR C1 FOR 
        select user_name from users;
declare a nvarchar(256);


   for r as c1 
    DO
    a := r.user_name;
   end for;

  select :a from dummy;
END
```

That's pretty much what Jobin already proposed. So I am not quite sure why his answer wasn't marked as correct.

Comment: No, you seem to have tried it with a too old SAP HANA release.

Comment: I am using **SPS 11** Release.

Comment: What error message do you get? The statement runs without any issue on SPS 11. I just copy&pasted it again into SAP HANA studio and the Web Based Development Workbench and ran it as it is ... no error whatsoever. 
Show the code you are using - then it's possible to tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: There was some syntactical error from my side.
Thanks a lot for Help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is very much possible.

```
DO 
BEGIN
....
DECLARE CURSOR C1 AS .....
....

END
```

Comment: Please try to include some actual code to help the OP

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Comment: I was trying the same syntax but it was wrong Could not execute 'DO BEGIN DECLARE CURSOR C1 FOR select id from sc_users'

SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: line 5 col 24 (at pos 62)

SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "declare": line 1 col 1 (at pos 1)

Could not execute 'for r as c1 DO a := r.id'

SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "for": line 1 col 1 (at pos 1)

Comment: instead of anonymous block i created a stored procedure to solve this problem

Comment: Please check the documentation before claiming something does not work. Anonymous blocks (DO BEGIN ... END) are only available as of SPS 10 and later.